# how can i prove the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, theorem-proving, inductive-logic-programming

```js
Exp(n)
  If n = 0
    Return 1
  End If
  
  If n%2==0
    temp = Exp(n/2)
    Return temp × temp
  Else //n is odd
    temp = Exp((n−1)/2)
    Return temp × temp × 2
  End if
```

how can i prove by strong induction in n that for all n ≥ 1, the number of multiplications made by
Exp (n) is ≤ 2 log2 n.

ps: Exp(n) = 2^n

Comment: `Exp(n)` is supposed to compute `Power(2, n)`?

Comment: I would have taken this question on [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use [**strong induction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction).

- First, prove that `Exp(0)` terminates and returns `2^0`.
- Let N be some arbitrary even nonnegative number.
- Assume the function `Exp` correctly calculates and returns `2^n` for every `n` in [0, N].
- Under this assumption, prove that `Exp(N+1)` and `Exp(N+2)` both terminate and correctly return `2^(N+1)` and `2^(N+2)`.

You're done! By induction it follows that for **any** nonnegative `N`, `Exp(N)` correctly returns `2^N`.

*PS: Note that in this post, `2^N` means "two to the power of N" and not "bitwise xor of the binary representations of 2 and N".*

Answer (score 0):

The program exactly applies the following recurrence:

```
P[0] = 1
n even -> P[n] -> P[n/2]²
n odd  -> P[n] -> P[(n-1)/2]².2
```

1. the program always terminates, because for `n>0`, `n/2` and `(n-1)/2 < n` and the argument of the recursive calls always decreases.

2. `P[n] = 2^n` is the solution of the recurrence. Indeed,

- `n = 0 -> 2^0 = 1`
- `n = 2m -> 2^n = (2^m)²`
- `n = 2m+1 -> 2^n = 2.(2^n)²`

and this covers all cases.

As every call decreases the number of significant bits of `n` by one and performs one or two multiplications, the total number does not exceed two times the number of significant bits.